# If $f$ is continuous at $z=a$ in a domain $D$ then $f$ is analytic on whole of $D$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, complex-numbers

> Let, $f$ be analytic in $D\setminus \{a\}$. Also, $f$ is continuous at $z=a$. Then prove that $f$ is analytic on whole of $D$.

We know from Riemann's Theorem, if $f$ is not analytic at $a$ and in a nbd. of $a$, if $f$ is bounded then either $f$ is analytic at $a$ or $f$ has removable singularity at $a$. But here how can I use the continuity condition to show $f$ is analytic ?

Comment: $f$ is continuous at $a\implies f$ is bounded in a nbd of $a$.

Comment: @SumantaDas just like in real?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not restrictive to assume that $a=0$ (with a translation).

Consider $g(z)=z^2f(z)$, for $z\in D$, $z\ne0$, and $g(0)=0$.

Prove that $g$ is differentiable at $0$. Thus it is differentiable over $D$, hence analytic over $D$. Hence it has a Taylor series expansion at $0$:
$$
g(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}b_nz^n
$$
but $b_0=b_1=0$ (prove it). Hence
$$
f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}b_{n+2}z^n
$$
is analytic in a neighborhood of $0$.

(Adapted from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Removable_singularity))

Comment: Where you use the continuity?

Comment: @Topo In showing $g$ is differentiable at $0$, boundedness of $f$ in a neighborhood of $0$ is needed.

Comment: Thus we get an analytic extension of $f$ at $z=0$. But $f$ is not analytic at $z=0$.

Comment: I've also doubt about my own question. Since $f$ is not analytic at $z=a$ and is continuous, so it has a singularity at $z=a$. As, $f$ is continuous at $z=a$ so the singularity must be removable. After removing that singularity we can redefine an analytic function in the whole domain $D$. But in that case the redefined function is the analytic extension of $f$. But how can I say about the analiticity of $f$ at $z=a$ ?

Comment: @Topo What's the doubt? Perhaps the phrasing can be ambiguous: we know that the function $f$ is analytic in $D\setminus\{a\}$ and continuous at $a$; the claim is that $f$ is also analytic at $a$. The problem states this and not that $f$ is not analytic at $a$ (because it *is* analytic at $a$, as proved).

Comment: "$f$ is also analytic at $a$" and " $f$ can be extend to an analytic function" are different. That's my doubt.

Comment: @Topo $f$ is defined at $a$. So there's no need to extend it.